# WordPress image upload error

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Im trying to upload an image to my wordpress schoolproject but WordPress gives me the error:

"Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2014/05. Is its parent directory writable by the server?"

So far I have given all the maps and images 0 restrictions. Which means that anyone can edit or move them.
I've read the WordPress forums about "miscellaneous" option at the dashboard. But I can't find it.

Im running WordPress on localhost. I have checked the search ways and names a couple of times, but that does not seems to be the problem.

What can I do to solve this problem? I rather not re-install all the WordPress files. It took me quite a while to get to where Iam now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its folder permission error in your server,

Set **"777"** permission for your uploads folder (give for its subfolders also).

For Your ref please check the below image.

[image]

Comment: Where do I find this folder? And what is it's name?
Thanks for answer

Comment: folder name is uploads, its located in wp-content\uploads.

Comment: Dont have one.
I got two maps, themes, plugins. And 1 file, index.php inside the content map.

Comment: please see my above answer, i have added ref image.in all wordpress sites this folder is created usually when you installed.

Comment: I dont have that folder. As I mentioned, when I click wp-content map I see 3 files. 2 maps, which is Themes and Plugins. And 1 php-file which is "index.php
the uploads map does not exist

Comment: ok, try to create the folder(uploads) in yourself as manually. in the same root

Comment: Yeh, now I can upload. But the image does not appear at my "view site".
Also, when I uncheck the "show header text with your image" box and click save changes nothing really happens. The page reloads and the box is still checked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52109/discussion-between-bharathi06-and-winterwind)